# Storm's ExecutorDetails Class

Tags: java, apache-storm

Currently, I am investigating **Storm**'s source code, and I came into the `ExecutorDetails` class of `scheduler` package. The class is simple, I just
want to the purpose of `startTask` and `endTask` fields and why in `hashcode()` method `endTask` was multiplied to 13, this is arbitrary or has some special meaning?

```
package backtype.storm.scheduler;

public class ExecutorDetails {
    int startTask;
    int endTask;

    public ExecutorDetails(int startTask, int endTask) {
        this.startTask = startTask;
        this.endTask = endTask;
    }

    public int getStartTask() {
        return startTask;
    }

    public int getEndTask() {
        return endTask;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null || !(other instanceof ExecutorDetails)) {
            return false;
        }

        ExecutorDetails executor = (ExecutorDetails) other;
        return (this.startTask == executor.startTask) && (this.endTask == executor.endTask);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return this.startTask + 13 * this.endTask;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + this.startTask + ", " + this.endTask + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure about `startTask` and `endTask`:

- I think that an executed gets a range of tasks assigned (from startTask to endTask).

For `hashCode()` (I am sure):

- Multiplying with 13 has no special meaning. The aim of `hashCode()` is to provide a unify distribution of hash values (with as few collisions as possible). Using prime numbers in the computation is a standard way (not only in Java) to achieve this goal.

Comment: thank you, I did not know about using prime numbers in situation like this